# Numpy masked array - find segment nearest to specific index

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, masked-array

I have a series of small images, stored as 2d numpy arrays. After applying a threshold, I turn the input image into a masked array (mask out values below threshold). Based on this, as shown in the plot below I end up with a number of different objects (2 sometimes more). How can I identify the object that is nearest to center of this masked image, and return an array containing only that object?

[image]

```
img = masked_array(
  data=[[--, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --,
         --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --,
         --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --],
        [--, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --,
         --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --,
         --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --],
        [--, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --,
         --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --,
         --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --],
        [--, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --,
         --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --,
         --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --],
        [--, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --,
         --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --,
         --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --],
        [--, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --,
         --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --,
         --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --],
        [--, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --,
         --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --,
         --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --],
        [--, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --,
         --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --,
         --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --],
        [--, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --,
         --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --,
         --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --],
        [--, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --,
         --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --,
         --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --],
        [--, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --,
         --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --,
         --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --],
        [--, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --,
         --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --,
         --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --],
        [--, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --,
         --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --,
         --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --],
        [--, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --,
         --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --,
         --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --],
        [--, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --,
         --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --,
         --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --],
        [--, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --,
         --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --,
         --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --],
        [--, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --,
         --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --,
         --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --],
        [--, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --,
         --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --,
         --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --],
        [--, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --,
         --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, 1.0, 1.0, --, --, --, --,
         --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --],
        [--, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --,
         --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, --, --, --, --,
         --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --],
        [--, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --,
         --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, --, --, --, --,
         --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --],
        [--, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --,
         --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, 1.0, 1.0, --, --, --, --,
         --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --],
        [--, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --,
         --, --, --, 1.0, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --,
         --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --],
        [--, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --,
         --, --, --, 1.0, 1.0, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --,
         --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --],
        [--, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --,
         --, --, --, 1.0, 1.0, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --,
         --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --],
        [--, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --,
         --, --, --, 1.0, 1.0, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --,
         --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --],
        [--, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --,
         --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --,
         --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --],
        [--, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --,
         --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --,
         --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --],
        [--, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --,
         --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --,
         --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --],
        [--, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --,
         --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --,
         --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --],
        [--, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --,
         --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --,
         --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --],
        [--, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --,
         --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --,
         --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --],
        [--, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --,
         --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --,
         --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --],
        [--, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --,
         --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --,
         --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --],
        [--, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --,
         --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --,
         --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --],
        [--, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --,
         --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --,
         --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --],
        [--, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --,
         --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --,
         --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --],
        [--, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --,
         --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --,
         --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --],
        [--, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --,
         --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --,
         --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --],
        [--, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --,
         --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --,
         --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --]],
  mask=[[ True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
          True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
          True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
          True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
          True,  True,  True,  True],
        [ True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
          True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
          True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
          True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
          True,  True,  True,  True],
        [ True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
          True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
          True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
          True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
          True,  True,  True,  True],
        [ True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
          True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
          True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
          True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
          True,  True,  True,  True],
        [ True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
          True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
          True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
          True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
          True,  True,  True,  True],
        [ True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
          True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
          True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
          True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
          True,  True,  True,  True],
        [ True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
          True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
          True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
          True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
          True,  True,  True,  True],
        [ True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
          True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
          True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
          True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
          True,  True,  True,  True],
        [ True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
          True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
          True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
          True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
          True,  True,  True,  True],
        [ True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
          True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
          True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
          True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
          True,  True,  True,  True],
        [ True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
          True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
          True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
          True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
          True,  True,  True,  True],
        [ True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
          True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
          True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
          True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
          True,  True,  True,  True],
        [ True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
          True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
          True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
          True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
          True,  True,  True,  True],
        [ True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
          True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
          True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
          True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
          True,  True,  True,  True],
        [ True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
          True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
          True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
          True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
          True,  True,  True,  True],
        [ True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
          True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
          True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
          True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
          True,  True,  True,  True],
        [ True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
          True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
          True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
          True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
          True,  True,  True,  True],
        [ True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
          True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
          True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
          True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
          True,  True,  True,  True],
        [ True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
          True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
          True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True, False, False,
          True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
          True,  True,  True,  True],
        [ True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
          True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
          True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True, False, False, False,
          True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
          True,  True,  True,  True],
        [ True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
          True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
          True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True, False, False, False,
          True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
          True,  True,  True,  True],
        [ True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
          True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
          True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True, False, False,
          True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
          True,  True,  True,  True],
        [ True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
          True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
          True, False,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
          True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
          True,  True,  True,  True],
        [ True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
          True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
          True, False, False,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
          True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
          True,  True,  True,  True],
        [ True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
          True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
          True, False, False,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
          True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
          True,  True,  True,  True],
        [ True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
          True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
          True, False, False,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
          True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
          True,  True,  True,  True],
        [ True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
          True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
          True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
          True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
          True,  True,  True,  True],
        [ True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
          True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
          True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
          True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
          True,  True,  True,  True],
        [ True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
          True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
          True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
          True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
          True,  True,  True,  True],
        [ True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
          True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
          True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
          True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
          True,  True,  True,  True],
        [ True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
          True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
          True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
          True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
          True,  True,  True,  True],
        [ True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
          True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
          True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
          True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
          True,  True,  True,  True],
        [ True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
          True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
          True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
          True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
          True,  True,  True,  True],
        [ True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
          True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
          True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
          True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
          True,  True,  True,  True],
        [ True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
          True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
          True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
          True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
          True,  True,  True,  True],
        [ True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
          True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
          True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
          True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
          True,  True,  True,  True],
        [ True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
          True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
          True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
          True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
          True,  True,  True,  True],
        [ True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
          True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
          True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
          True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
          True,  True,  True,  True],
        [ True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
          True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
          True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
          True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
          True,  True,  True,  True],
        [ True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
          True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
          True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
          True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
          True,  True,  True,  True]],
  fill_value=1e+20)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Final result:
[image]

### 4 steps involved here:

1. get index of the center and indices of non-masked points
2. get the closest point to the center
3. get the "object" in which the point closest to the center belongs. You can get this using [opencv connected components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46441893/connected-component-labeling-in-python) (or [findContour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64345584/how-to-properly-use-cv2-findcontours-on-opencv-version-4-4-0))
4. Modify the image to keep only the object you are interested in

## Step 1

Getting indices of non masked point to get the one closest to the center

```py
>>> center = [[img.shape[1] // 2, img.shape[0] // 2]]
>>> center
[[20, 20]]
>>> indices = np.array(list(zip(*img.nonzero())))
>>> indices 
array([[18, 25],
       [18, 26],
       [19, 24],
       [19, 25],
       [19, 26],
       [20, 24],
       [20, 25],
       [20, 26],
       [21, 25],
       [21, 26],
       [22, 19],
       [23, 19],
       [23, 20],
       [24, 19],
       [24, 20],
       [25, 19],
       [25, 20]], dtype=int64)
```

## Step 2

Compute the distance. I'll use scipy for this

```py
>>> from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist
>>> distance = cdist(indices, center)
>>> distance
array([[5.38516481],
       [6.32455532],
       [4.12310563],
       [5.09901951],
       [6.08276253],
       [4.        ],
       [5.        ],
       [6.        ],
       [5.09901951],
       [6.08276253],
       [2.23606798],
       [3.16227766],
       [3.        ],
       [4.12310563],
       [4.        ],
       [5.09901951],
       [5.        ]])
>>> np.argmin(distance)
10
>>> distance[10]
array([2.23606798])
>>> closest_point = indices[10]
>>> closest_point
array([22, 19], dtype=int64)
```

## Step 3

Find the "object" ( = the connected component) closest to the center.
I'll use OpenCV for this

```py
>>> import cv2
>>> N_cc, cc = cv2.connectedComponents(img.data.astype(np.uint8))
>>> N_cc
3 # 3 objects on your image: the 2 'black' and the white one
>>> obj = np.array(
    list(zip(
*np.where(cc == cc[closest_point[0], closest_point[1]]) # getting all the points from the connected component having the same label as the point closest to the center
)) 
)
>>> obj
array([[22, 19], # the closest point to the center
       [23, 19], # and all its neighbours in the same object
       [23, 20],
       [24, 19],
       [24, 20],
       [25, 19],
       [25, 20]], dtype=int64)
```

## Step 4

Keep only the main object in the original image

```py
>>> img.mask.fill(True)
>>> img.mask[obj[:, 0], obj[:, 1]] = False # numpy version of: for i in obj: img.mask[i[0], i[1]] = False
>>> img.nonzero()
(array([22, 23, 23, 24, 24, 25, 25], dtype=int64),
 array([19, 19, 20, 19, 20, 19, 20], dtype=int64))
```